# Eclipse: "problems" tag does not work

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

At home, I use Eclipse on Linux, but here, at work, I'm on Windows. I suppose they're set up differently, or I set them up differently. But, at home, if I have code like:

```
$variable = array());
```

I get something in the "problems" tab in Eclipse. Here, no. I've been digging through the options and I've googled the problem (but the words "problems tag" are too general). What did I miss. I must have a dangling parenthesis somewhere, but it'll take me forever to find it on my own.

Comment: Is the PDT (http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) installed in your environment both at home and at work?  You may be able to edit files with both installations but if you lack PHP support on one you won't get errors reported.

Comment: It is installed on both. I get syntax highlighting and it fetches data from the manual on php.net. But not the "problems" tab never tells me that anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the project properties (Right click on the project, last menu item), at the Builders tab: there should be a Validation and a Script builder added (at least I have those two in Eclipse 3.6, and the Script builder is required for PHP). If they are missing, there is a chance, that the project lost its PHP nature.

If the nature is missing, look for the .project file in the root folder of the project (it is by default hidden, but you could either show .* files, or view it in the File navigator outside Eclipse. At the end of file, there should the PHP nature be added:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
</natures>
```

If the nature and builders are set correctly, I don't know, what might have caused your problem.

**Update**: the relevant part of my .project file looks as following: try to update yours.

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.dltk.core.scriptbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: There only is a Validation Builder, no script builder. I'm going to look that up.

Comment: I updated the answer to contain the builder info from the .project.